# How can I automate the creation of SQL Server Agent Notifications on job failure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

There are no alerts setup on any of my SQL Server Agent jobs ( for failure,severity code etc.).

Is there is a script to help or do I have to create an alert manually for every single job?

Comment: Did you Google for this at all? http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/automating-sql-server-agent-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to add ,before you set up alerts for job notification (FAIL or SUCCESS) it is important you would require to configure Database Mail on the SQL server instance. Read [here](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/database-mail-configuration/) on how to configure the said above.

Once Database mail has been configured, [you will need to create Sql Server Agent Operators](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-operators/)  to get notification not only for SQL job failures but also corruption and other major failures/outages.

Now to go ahead and automate the creation of alerts you can follow the steps described [How to setup SQL Server alerts and email operator notifications](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/).

Also, a simple script to set the various severity alerts can be found at [No SQL Server Agent Alerts Configured](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-alerts/)